# How do I measure the alcohol of a fruit beer?

Tags: fruit, measurements, alcohol-content

According to some recipes I have seen, a simple way to make a fruit beer is to make a regular "base" beer, and then rack it on top of the fruit after about a week of fermentation.

In that case, how do I measure the alcohol level?

(The classic OG measurement would not include the fruit part. The calculation would need to take into account alcohol from primary, sugar & liquid volume added to secondary, and alcohol generated in secondary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres a good bit of information from the mad fermentationist about alcohol content and fruit in beer: http://www.themadfermentationist.com/2010/10/adding-fruit-to-beer-increases-alcohol.html

Fruit also contains other things (water) that will further dilute the beer, so the effect will be minimal, if anything at all, and can actually cause the total alcohol content by volume to decrease.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. And for the record, I was not about to assume anything regarding higher or lower alcohol levels!! :D

Answer (score 2):

Morebeer has a simple table for common fruits, 
http://morebeer.com/articles/fruit_in_beer

It is unlikely you will lower the alcohol content unless the addition is primarily water, not at all sweet, or your beer is extremely high alcohol to begin with.